# how can i format jquery datepicker as "25-JAN-2009"

Tags: jquery, format, datepicker

I would have thought this was:

```
.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mmm-yyyy' });
```

for month, I get some number that I don't understnad where they are coming from?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate), a single M is "Month name short" and "yy" is "Four Digit Year."

```
dd-M-yy
```

Comment: This is a great and straight forward way to achieve this

Answer (score 23):

This is a case where looking into the [**documentation**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) is most helpful:

```
*  d - day of month (no leading zero)
* dd - day of month (two digit)
* o - day of the year (no leading zeros)
* oo - day of the year (three digit)
* D - day name short
* DD - day name long
* m - month of year (no leading zero)
* mm - month of year (two digit)
* M - month name short
* MM - month name long
* y - year (two digit)
* yy - year (four digit)
* @ - Unix timestamp (ms since 01/01/1970)
* '...' - literal text
* '' - single quote
* anything else - literal text
```

Answer (score 12):

You want:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
```

See the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate).

The date format strings are somewhat non-standard:

`d` - day of month (no leading zero)
`dd` - day of month (two digit)
`o` - day of the year (no leading zeros)
`oo` - day of the year (three digit)
`D` - day name short
`DD` - day name long
`m` - month of year (no leading zero)
`mm` - month of year (two digit)
`M` - month name short
`MM` - month name long
`y` - year (two digit)
`yy` - year (four digit)
`@` - Unix timestamp (ms since 01/01/1970)
`'...'` - literal text
`''` - single quote
anything else - literal text

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is `dd-M-yy`

Alternatively you can use the **[monthNamesShort](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-monthNamesShort)** option for custom names ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AUI Datepicker / Datepicketselect components then dateFormat usage is a bit different.

for eg: if you want to display 01-Jan-2014, you will have to use
`dateFormat:'%d-%b-%Y'`

following is the documentation that explains different formats:
http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/api/classes/DataType.Date.html

My working code: (on Liferay with AUI)

```
<div id="myDatepicker"></div>
  <input type="text" name="myDateValue" id="myDateValue" size="9" /> 

<aui:script>
  AUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(A) {
     new A.DatePickerSelect(
       {
         appendOrder: ['d', 'm', 'y'],
        calendar: {
        dateFormat: '%d-%b-%Y'
    },
    boundingBox: '#myDatepicker',
    trigger: '#myDateValue'
  }
).render();
}
);
</aui:script>
```