# show monthNameShort in datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using datepicker of jquery ui
now it show the month names like "March"
I want show them in monthNamesShort format like "Mar"
How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an uppercase 'M' in the month part of the format string.

[how can i format jquery datepicker as "25-JAN-2009"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057157/how-can-i-format-jquery-datepicker-as-25-jan-2009)

---

Edit

I'm sure there is a nicer way, but what about manually giving it the month names?

```
$('#member_dob').datepicker({
            monthNames: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
});
```

Comment: i don't want format the result, i want format the month name of titlebar between the arrows