# How to set the datetimepicker month name format as three digit eg. Jan

Tags: datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker. I want the datetimepicker format as short month name eg. `Jan`. My code is below and it shows the full month name now as `January`. How to make it `Jan`?

```js
$('.datepickersren').datetimepicker({             
    format: 'MMMM',
    viewMode: "months", 
})
```

Please note that the `format:'M'` is not working in datetimepicker. It will work on the datepicker only. If we give `format:'M'` in datetimepicker, the month format is month number eg. 5, 6, 7 etc. Not the month names like `Jan`, `Feb,` etc.

Comment: $('.datepickersren').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i format jquery datepicker as "25-JAN-2009"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057157/how-can-i-format-jquery-datepicker-as-25-jan-2009)

Comment: For datetimepicker, format: 'M' is not working.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.datepickersren').datetimepicker({             
    format: 'MMM',
    viewMode: "months", 
})
```

The above code is working for me and the `format: 'MMM'` displays the three letter month name as `Jan`, `Feb` etc. Thank you all for the response.

Comment: It works because eonasdan-datetimepicker uses moment and as moment [docs says](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) `MMM` stands for `Jan`, `Feb`, ..., `Nov`, `Dec`.

Answer (score 1):

**A single M is "Month name short"**

```
      $('.datepickersren').datetimepicker({             
          format: 'dd-M-yy',
          viewMode: "months", 
      })
```

Comment: Is it ui or bootstrap datetimepicker?

Comment: Bootstrap datetimepicker.